# Can action delegates point to methods having a return type?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Can action delegates point to methods having a return type?
For e.g

```
Action a = () => Add();  
int Add()
{
  return 5 + 6;
}
```

The above code compiles. Now if I write the above something like

```
Action a = new Action(Add);
```

This does not compile. Could anyone please help me to understand the logic behind this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Action a = () => Add();  
int Add()
{
  return 5 + 6;
}
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
Action a = ExecuteAdd;
int Add()
{
  return 5 + 6;
}
void ExecuteAdd() 
{
  Add();
}
```

And `Action a = new Action(ExecuteAdd);` would compile.

The reason being that `() => Add();` actually creates an [anonymous method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-methods). Assigning it to a variable of type `Action` infers the return type `void`.

Answer (score 0):

First example creates an anonymous method that calls `Add`.

```
Action a = () => Add();
           ^        
Anonymous method with void return type.
```

If you want to assign method to `Action` you should do this:

```
Action a = Add;
```